# cassandra migrate between different versions

Tags: version, cassandra, migrate

I migrated from old version 0.6 to new version following instructions in NEWS.txt.
To migrate successfully, I need to delete all files in commitlog directory and all LocationInfo*.db in system directory.

I also tried to migrate in reverse direction. That said, I tried to go from 0.7.2 to old version 0.6. I find there are two cases.

first case, If I do not do any change in 0.7.2, to back to 0.6, I just need to delete files in commitlog and system directories. And then do similar steps as upgrading to 0.7.2. In such way, I am back to 0.6

second case, If I do some modification in 0.7.2, for example, insert a new row into a column family. I cannot go back. I need to delete files in commitlog and system directories. In the meantime, I need to delete some files in data directory. These files store the new row I put into column family. After that, I can go back to 0.6.

Is it possible to go back old version 0.6 without deleting my new data added in 0.7.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First, as NEWS says, you should not delete your commitlogs when upgrading from 0.6 to 0.7; that is a good way to lose data.  You should use drain instead.

2) 0.6 cannot read 0.7 data files, but you could export w/ sstable2json and re-import with json2sstable.

Comment: Yes, Node drain is used. it would empty commitlog. If the commitlog is not empty, I should run node drain again?

Comment: I mean if the commitlog is not empty after running node drain, is it safe to delete commit logs now?